# how can I easily produce this screen related to end task?

Tags: windows

When I restart my computer, a restart can be prevented sometimes when a window pops up and says "End Program .......exe"  Ending program please wait.
Then after the blue indicator reaches the end, sometimes or always, you get another screen that says "The program is not responding.." and you can click Cancel or End Now. And if you click Cancel, it doesn't shutdown. That happens in XP anyway

Is there any small process I can download that would do that when a restart is issued?

I've seen some processes do it.

Comment: @Psycogeek not sure what you mean by the purpose of testing. But I want it for the latter, the purpose of  being able to make a shutdown/restart only go ahead if I want it to. I don't know if shutdown -a would do it but i'd like that method described in my question, though if you know of another method, i'm interested.

Comment: @Psycogeek  I'm not trying to shut it down or restart it i'm trying to stop it shutting down or restarting, like when I install a program and just click next next next and the damn thing decides to restart my computer.

Comment: Ok now that is starting to make sence. To stop a programs or even the systems own, shutdown calls , and force them to have an abortable delay instead.  That I dont know, I do know that some of the programs will have a seperate shutdown exe item, and most will just make a system call to shutdown. and you want to insure that some Notification exists for it, beyond the programs endless NEXTing that ends in disasters :-) ?

Comment: @Psycogeek  it works for a program I just tested it on(prio on softpedia is a little program that tries to restart the computer). Shutdownguard prevented it. You can post that as an answer and i'll see what other answers come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one shutdown prevention tool item ShutdownGuard
 http://code.google.com/p/shutdownguard/
A good fuller web post on it is here
http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/11/14/shutdownguard-tells-windows-where-to-stick-automatic-restarts/

The program puts up a notification into the tray, which a person can choose what they want to do. It would need much testing, and might not work in some situations.

It would be interesting to know if the same thing can be done without any locking by group policy ,and within the system itself, without any added program item.

Comment: Here is some description from the page for shutdownguard http://code.google.com/p/shutdownguard/ ShutdownGuard tries to prevents applications to shutdown,reboot or log offYour computer When it prevents a shutdown in Windows XP,it will pop up in the tray and ask you if you want to continue.In Vista and Windows 7,you will see another dialog

Note that ShutdownGuard will not be able to prevent all shutdowns, since some programs explicitly tells Windows to force the shutdown. This means some programs will still be able to shutdown your computer!and if of interest,the author's site stefansundin.com